# 12-bit grayscale jpeg to 8-bit grayscale jpeg C/C++

Tags: c

As an assignment I need to convert a 12-bit jpeg image to BMP file without using any library files or headers (except math.h and stdio.h) even string.h is forbidden. I have coded most of it and i can now convert 8-bit jpeg to BMP but i do not understand how 12 bit jpeg works and I do not know how can i convert 12-bit jpeg file to a 8-bit jpeg.

(my source code is in c)

I need a good source for understanding how 12 bit jpeg works
And if it is possible it would be great if someone can help me about conversion.

Comment: You actually coded the JPEG decompression yourself? That's pretty impressive. If you can do that, then you should be able to easily understand how to handle arbitrary depth JPEG images.

Comment: Insane assignment of course, with those restrictions. But that's not a good reason to close it as "offtopic, library request".

Comment: 12-bit jpeg is a very exotic format, are you sure you want it? If your assignment doesn't specifically say you have to do 12 bit, you probably don't.

Comment: Basics image proccess part is not new to me , huffman coding and DCT parts was my biggest problem then, i studied and read a lot of sample codes and created my final code. I am currently thinking about dividing cromatic colour values by 16 to get 0-255 but it doesn't seems to be working in general.

Comment: I have to use 12-bit jpeg. My superior was not clear to my when i first acquired this task and i recently learned that i should convert 12-bit jpeg to BMP

Comment: The JPEG compression standard is not freely available. It costs ~US$70 directly from the standards group. If you have subscriber access e.g. via your uni then you are in a better position to read and understand the standard then most of us. If not, ask your prof to shell out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12 bit jpeg appears to be just like 8 bit jpeg. It's easier to see how it works from the compression side, but once you understand that decompression is straightforward.

With 12 bits jpegs, the DCT step deducts 2^11 from each pixel value before doing a DCT transform. Obviously the results of the DCT will be somewhat larger, but that's no big deal. You still pick the biggest coefficients and store those, same as you'd do for 8 bits jpeg.

Comment: Thanks a lot so if i arrange my pixel values from 12 bit to 8 bit it should be enough. I was afraid that i may need to change my 8x8 huffman block system

Comment: @BerkTaskin: No, 12 bits depth JPEG's still have 8x8 DCTs. As for the output, I don't know if you intend to produce 8 bits BMP's, but if so then yes you'd have to divide the values by 2^4